# Cannot set property of SymbolSuggest of undefined

Tags: jquery, properties, symbols

I am trying to  get the Symbol for Company name with the below code jQuery.
I am new to this.

I am getting an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SymbolSuggest' of undefined '. Please suggest how I can eliminate this.

```
var query;
            query = 'Yahoo';
            if (query.length > 0) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc",
                    data: {
                        query: query
                    },
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonp: "callback",
                    jsonpCallback: "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback&callback=?",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try typing YAHOO in web console. We will get something like this:

Object {namespace: function, log: function, register: function, env: Object, util: Object…}

Actually it should have been:

Object {Finance: Object}

This means actually your YAHOO object does not have attribute Finance. So in effect YAHOO.Finance is undefined and your trying to call SymbolSuggest of an undefined object. This is the error.

For solution make sure your are loading

`<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script>`

Also initialise your YAHOO object:

```
var YAHOO = {
  Finance: {
    SymbolSuggest: {}
  }
};
```

Now your code should be working.